# Find element that has text starting with/containing except full match in Imacros

Tags: imacros

I know I can match with iMacros elements like this:

```
<button ...>Confirm action A</button>
```

with

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Confirm<SP>action<SP>A
```

but the problem is, that sometimes I don't know **exact** text on the button, but I know that it will **start with** or **contain** some specific text, in that case "Confirm".

Is it possible to match elements that contain or start with some text, instead of exact-full-text matching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, use * instead word you don't know like this:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Confirm*A
```